# Python: Determine whether list of lists contains a defined sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, function, loops

I have a list of sublists, and I want to see if any of the integer values from the first sublist plus one are contained in the second sublist. For all such values, I want to see if that value plus one is contained in the third sublist, and so on, proceeding in this fashion across all sublists. If there is a way of proceeding in this fashion from the first sublist to the last sublist, I wish to return True; otherwise I wish to return False. For each value in the first sublist, I want to see if one can find that value plus n in each sublist reading left to right, where n is the index value of that sublist within the larger list.. (Sorry for the clumsy phrasing--I'm not sure how to clean up my language without using many more words.)

EDIT: (The previous articulation of desired output is ambiguous.) For each value in the first sublist, I want to see if one can find that value plus n in each sublist reading left to right, where n is the index value of that sublist within the larger list.

Here's what I wrote.

```
a = [ [1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[6],[7] ]

def find_list_traversing_walk(l):

    for i in l[0]:

        index_position = 0
        first_pass = 1
        walking_current_path = 1

        while walking_current_path == 1:

            if first_pass == 1:
                first_pass = 0
                walking_value = i

            if walking_value+1 in l[index_position + 1]:

                index_position += 1
                walking_value  += 1

                if index_position+1 == len(l):
                    print "There is a walk across the sublists for initial value ", walking_value - index_position
                    return True

            else:
                walking_current_path = 0

    return False

print find_list_traversing_walk(a)
```

My question is: Have I overlooked something simple here, or will this function return True for all true positives and False for all true negatives? Are there easier ways to accomplish the intended task? I would be grateful for any feedback others can offer!

Comment: In your example, would ```find_list_traversing_walk(a)``` return False?

Comment: my example should evaulate to True. I think I came closer to better language in my comment on @alfasin's answer: For each value in the first sublist, I want to see if one can find that value plus n in each sublist reading left to right, where n is the index value of that sublist within the larger list. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is the number of items in each sublist constrained or can a sublist have three or four or any number of items?

Comment: Theoretically, there could be any finite number of values in a sublist, though it's extremely unlikely for any sublist to contain more than three values. Check out @Warren's answer below--it's genius.

Comment: Yep, I upvoted it when I read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the desired operation as a *reduction* on a sequence of sets where the reducing operation is the following function:

```
In [25]: def func(x, y):
   ....:     return set([t+1 for t in x]) & set(y)
   ....:
```

That is, `func` takes two collections, adds 1 to each element in the first collection, and returns the intersection of that and the second collection.  Apply this function sequentially across `a`.  If the final result is not an empty set, the answer is True:

```
In [29]: a = [ [1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[6],[7] ]

In [30]: bool(reduce(func, a))
Out[30]: True

In [31]: b = [ [1],[2,4],[5] ]

In [32]: bool(reduce(func, b))
Out[32]: False
```

(`bool` converts a non-empty set to True and an empty set to False.)

Note that if the input is typically a very long sequence, and you expect to know that the answer is False within a few steps, this is not a very efficient solution, since it always traverses the entire input.

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing out the 'reduce' function--that's pretty neat!

Comment: I accepted this answer because it is elegant and because you helped to walk me through it.

Comment: *"... how does func() know..."*:  `func()` doesn't know; it is `reduce` that calls `func()` with the appropriate arguments.  `reduce` (in effect) computes `func(...(func(func(a[0], a[1]), a[2])...), a[n-1])`.  It is easier to express that with infix notation.  That is, suppose the reducing operation was addition, and the input sequence is `a = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4]`. Then the reduction is `((((1 + 3) + 5) + 2) + 4)`.  A reduction like this is an example of a `fold`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29

Comment: Many thanks, @Warren! I am very grateful for your thorough explanation and the link.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there easier ways to accomplish the intended task?

Yes, it will be easier to define a recursive solution:

```
def find(lst, index):
    if index == len(lst)-1:
        return True
    for i in lst[index]:
        if i+1 in lst[index+1]:
            return find(lst, index+1)
    else:
        return False             

a = [ [1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[6],[7] ]
print find(a, 0) # prints "True"

a = [ [1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[6],[7], [9] ]
print find(a, 0) # prints "False"
```

**UPDATE**
What you describe in your comment is a bit more complex (the need for the `next+1` to be one of the "guys" that were used before) - but not much:

```
def find(lst, part_res, index):
    if index == len(lst)-1:
        return True

    found = False
    new_part_res = []
    for i in part_res:
        if i+1 in lst[index+1]:
            found = True
            new_part_res.append(i+1)

    if not found:
        return False
    else:
        return find(lst, new_part_res, index+1)


a = [ [1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[6],[7] ] 
print find(a, a[0], 0) # True

a = [ [1],[2,4],[5] ]
print find(a, a[0], 0) # False
```

Comment: ah, interesting thought, but `a = [ [1],[2,4],[5] ]` yields True but I want it to return False, because 1+1=2 [so far so good], but 2+1 !=5. For each value in the first sublist, I want to see if one can find that value plus n in each sublist reading left to right, where n is the index value of that sublist within the larger list. Does that make sense? (Wittgenstein is rolling over in his grave.)

Comment: Thank you--this is great! I'm very sorry I wasn't more clear to begin with. Is there literature I can consult to be better equipped to describe this kind of problem in the future? Thank you for responding to my note, and for updating your answer!

Comment: @duhaime I don't know about literature... but I think that what usually does the work is the old saying: "practice makes perfect" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I also thought it was expressed better recursively.  If I understood your problem correctly, this is what I came up with.

```
a = [ [1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[6],[7] ]
b = [ [1],[2,4],[5] ]
c = [ [1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[6, 4],[5, 7] ]

def foo(data):
    if len(data) == 1:
        return True
    return all(item + 1 in data[1] for item in data[0]) and foo(data[1:])

print foo(a), foo(b), foo(c)
>>> 
False False True
>>>
```

Comment: sorry, @wwii, that I didn't express my desired output clearly enough. I would wish to return True for list a, as there is a path 3,4,5,6,7 across which each step is equal to the prior value + 1. I really need a better vocabulary to describe this sort of phenomenon. Recursion must be what I'm after. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  This looks like a graph problem and you want to know if there is a path from *left to right*.  I'll noodle some more.

Comment: @wwii nope, that's not a path in a graph, if it was, my first solution would work :)